# two methods in a class so close in what they do

Tags: php

I have this class that has these two methods that are so closely related to the each other. I do not want to pass the flags so I kept them separate. I was wondering if there is a way to rewrite it so that I do not have to repeat so closely!

```
  class Test extends Controller
    {
        public static function nonFormattedData($param)
        {
            $arr = array();
            if (is_array($param)) {
                $i = 0;
                $sql = "
                    select *
                    from table1
                    where
                    ";


                if (isset($param['startDate'])) {
                    $sql .= "   date_created between ? AND  ?";
                    $arr[] = $param['startDate'];
                    $arr[] = $param['endDate'];
                    $i++;
                }
                if (isset($param['amount']) && !empty($param['amount'])) {

                    if ($i > 0) $sql .= " AND ";
                    $sql .= " balance= ?";
                    $arr[] = $param['amount'];
                    $i++;
                }
                if (isset($param) && !empty($param['amount'])) {

                    if ($i > 0) $sql .= " AND ";
                    $sql .= " balance= ?";
                    $arr[] = $param['amount'];
                    $i++;
                }
                if (isset($param['createdBy']) && !empty($param['createdBy'])) {

                    if ($i > 0) $sql .= " AND ";
                    $sql .= " column2 like '%Created By: " . $param['createdBy'] . "%'";
                }
                $sql .= ' group by id.table1 ';
                $rs = Query::RunQuery($sql, $arr);
                foreach ($rs as $row) {
                    $records = new Account();
                    $results[] = $records;
                }
                return $results;
            }
        }




        public static function formattedData($serArray, $orderBy = "giftcardaccount_id desc", $offset = 0, $limit = 10)
        {
                $arr = array();
            if (is_array($param)) {
                $i = 0;
                $sql = "
                    select *
                    from table1
                    where
                    ";


                if (isset($param['startDate'])) {
                    $sql .= "   date_created between ? AND  ?";
                    $arr[] = $param['startDate'];
                    $arr[] = $param['endDate'];
                    $i++;
                }
                if (isset($param['amount']) && !empty($param['amount'])) {

                    if ($i > 0) $sql .= " AND ";
                    $sql .= " balance= ?";
                    $arr[] = $param['amount'];
                    $i++;
                }
                if (isset($param) && !empty($param['amount'])) {

                    if ($i > 0) $sql .= " AND ";
                    $sql .= " balance= ?";
                    $arr[] = $param['amount'];
                    $i++;
                }
                if (isset($param['createdBy']) && !empty($param['createdBy'])) {

                    if ($i > 0) $sql .= " AND ";
                    $sql .= " column2 like '%Created By: " . $param['createdBy'] . "%'";
                }
                $sql .= ' group by id.table1 ';
                $rs = Query::RunQuery($sql, $arr);

                return array("data" => $rs);
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: are you looking for a solution with cake components or why is this tagged cakephp?

Comment: no but its built with cakephp

Comment: In formattedData() you you use the local variable $param but you don't pass it into the method.  Am I missing something or is this a typo?

Comment: this code does not look like cakephp at all. straight SQL and Query::RunQuery() are very much "un-cake-way" of doing things.

Comment: That isn't built with CakePHP. A `Query` class doesn't exist within CakePHP and `class Test extends Controller` would be `class TestsController extends AppController` if it were CakePHP. So unless you're building something completely custom *next* to CakePHP and ignoring CakePHP all together... this has nothing to do with CakePHP.

Comment: This is definitely not CakePHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have one method, but with an optional formatting options object/array?

```
public static function getData($params, $formatting = null) {
    // continue as normal, adding formatting if it's there
}
```